# First Salt project after Salt-Cloud setup

Tags: salt-stack

I have successfully setup Salt-Cloud (on Fedora 22) to provision a minion on Digital Ocean. However, the documentation is light on how to proceed after this.

I am able to run states from `/srv/salt` but I'd like to know the correct approach to now set up a Salt project in my home directory.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "set up a Salt project in my home directory.", it can mean lot of things. With VM or without VM? Do you want to make the local development salt deployment use the similar salt-cloud deployment method?

Saltstack online documentation is sort of "intermediate reference" than a good tutorial reference (confusion for newbie).  I suggest you get a third party books such as "Saltstack introduction".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this](http://bencane.com/2013/09/03/getting-started-with-saltstack-by-example-automatically-installing-nginx/) article, I was able to edit the `/etc/salt/master` config file to change:

```
#file_roots:
#base:
#- /srv/salt
```

to:

```
#file_roots:
#base:
#- ~/salt
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: please note that entries starting with `#` are commented out lines. I suspect that changing commented out lines didn't solve your problem.